# Angular: intersectionObserver and different threshold

Tags: angular, intersection-observer

I have observers set up for my paragraphs where once it scrolls a certain threshold, it fades in the new paragraph and fades out the upper paragraphs.  However, the paragraph fades out sooner than I would like and I want to have the animation of the paragraph being invisible again only happen if they are off the viewport.  Right now, the paragraph disappears as soon as they hit the threshold value, but is there a way to set up another threshold for disappearing while keeping the threshold for when the element appears?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpwhxc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :-)</p>
      <p #p1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet.
      </p>
      <p #p2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet.
      </p>
      <p #p3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet.
      </p>
      <p #p4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet.
      </p>
      <p #p5>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet.
      </p>
      
      <div class="sites-circle" [ngClass]="mouseMove ? 'onMove' : 'notMove'">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  const threshold = 0.7; // how much % of the element is in view
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
          entries.forEach((entry) => {
              if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                // this.vertImage1.nativeElement.classList.toggle('activate');
                // this.vertImage1.nativeElement.classList.add('activate');
                entry.target.classList.add('activate');
                  // observer.disconnect(); // disconnect if you want to stop observing else it will rerun every time its back in view. Just make sure you disconnect in ngOnDestroy instead
              }
              else{
                
                entry.target.classList.remove('activate');
              }
          });
      },
      { threshold }
  );
  observer.observe(this.p1.nativeElement);
  observer.observe(this.p2.nativeElement);
  observer.observe(this.p3.nativeElement);
  observer.observe(this.p4.nativeElement);
  observer.observe(this.p5.nativeElement);

}
@ViewChild('p1') p1!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('p2') p2!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('p3') p3!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('p4') p4!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('p5') p5!: ElementRef;
}
```

CSS:

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size:35px;

  opacity:0;
  transition:.4s;
}



.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

p.activate{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#thresholds

The threshold option can accept an array which will trigger callback execution for each intersection ration value. So i think you must update your code this way

```
const threshold = [0.0, 0.7]; // add a 0.0 mark to trigger callback when your element is completly outside
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.classList.add('activate');
      } else {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio === 0.0) //This condition ensure we remove class only on 0.0 mark and not on 0.7 mark
          entry.target.classList.remove('activate');
      }
    });
  },
  { threshold }
);
```

Updated Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaktud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts%3AL1,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts